# Alternative to writing 15 if else statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm wondering if there is a better way doing this: I'm checking to see if a calculation is 0, if 0 nothing happens. If not 0 money gets added to player. The problem is that I have to check 15 different calculations of dividends right now, how would this be smart to do? I could do 15 if/else statements but that would be messy. My one idea was to have the code below but if the statements true, to continue the loop to also check the other statements and if true act on them. Is this possible in Python?

My other idea was to do a while loop and basically every 60 seconds, just setattr the dividens for all stocks even if the dividens are 0, but I think this has a chance to become a bug if the player does something else during the execution. Some sample code:

```
import random
import sys
import time
import os

def playerStatus():
    playerStatus.playerMoney = 10000
    playerStatus.playerLoan = 0

def dividends():
    while True: 

        networthCalc()
        pm = playerStatus.playerMoney
        print("cash:", pm)
        dividends.aapl = networthCalc.aapl / random.randint (20,30) 
        dividends.goog = networthCalc.goog / random.randint (20,30)
        time.sleep(1)
        if dividends.aapl > 0: 
            newCash = dividends.aapl + pm
            setattr(playerStatus, "playerMoney", newCash)
            print("aapl payed div:", dividends.aapl)

        elif dividends.goog > 0: 
            newCash = dividends.goog + pm
            setattr(playerStatus, "playerMoney", newCash)
            print("goog payed div:", dividends.goog)
        else:
            pass

def networthCalc():
    networthCalc.aapl = getattr(stockPrice, "aapl") * getattr(showAssets, "aapl")
    networthCalc.goog = getattr(stockPrice, "goog") * getattr(showAssets, "goog")

def showAssets():
    showAssets.aapl = 10
    showAssets.goog = 10

def stockPrice():
    stockPrice.aapl = 200
    stockPrice.goog = 200

playerStatus()
showAssets()
stockPrice()
networthCalc()
dividends()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but can you put all of the values in a numpy array and check:

> arr[arr==0]

That will give you a boolean array which you can use to index only the stocks you want

Comment: Why? If you can have a mapping from a position in the array to the stock just loop through and only execute on the ones that are True

Comment: User, Thanks for the idea. Since it does not matter who pays it, I can just write one loop that adds all the dividends up and then adds that to the player money. I assume that with a numpy array I could also get who paid what, this might be useful in the future. Consider this solved.

Answer (score 1):

Build a list of the operations and store it's values to process. If you want to know if there's any of the calculation is greater than 0 use teh function `any()`

```
x = 3
calculations = [x+1,x+2,x+(-3)]
if any(calculations):
    #do something 
    print("there's something above 0")
```

If you need to do specific calculations based on which every "function" returns greater than zero, you can create the calculation as functions and create a dictionary to host the results as values with the function name as keys (we put the creation of the calculate in a function because we want to get values dynamically and not the moment the dictionary was created, hence we create a new one each time based on the value being passed in). That way you know which one return what values. If you want to process based on what return greater than 0, just create another dictionary and use the keys returned as keys to the `to_do` dictionary:

```
def aapl_calc(value):
    return value + 5

def goo_calc(value):
    return value -2 

def calculate_everything(x):
    return {"aapl":aapl_calc(x), "goo":goo_calc(x)}

def appl_to_do():
    print("appl was greater than zero")

def goo_to_do():
    print("goo was greater than zero")

to_do = {"aapl": appl_to_do, "goo":goo_to_do}

results = calculate_everything(2)
#checking if anything is greater than zero is easy
if any(results.values()):
    print("something return as 0")

#creating a list of greater than 0 to use as keys
greater_than_zero = [key for key, val in results.items() if val]

#run each of the values greater than 0
for each in greater_than_zero:
    to_do[each]()
```

But there's nothing wrong with `if` statements, would be cleaner to read.